# Use nested loop to copy files in filelist to folders in folderlist, with batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, copy, nested

I want to simultaneously read from a file list and a folder list and copy each file into each folder, with a file rename.

Below is my original code. The outside loop doesn't increment. I've tried every which way to apply what I've read about loops and delayed expansion but nothing has worked.

Can someone please tell me how to fix the code or what to use instead?

EDIT to clarify problem: With each iteration, "echo src" echoes 1st line in Filelist.txt. Never changes. On the other hand, "echo dest" **does** go through folderlist.txt as expected (desired).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: var is set in calling routine
SET "newname=%var%_filename_0.jpg"   
    FOR /F  %%G IN (Filelist.txt) DO (
    FOR /F %%H IN (Folderlist.txt) DO (
        SET src=%%G
        SET dest=%%H
            echo src is !src!
            echo dest is !dest!
            REM Here with each iteration do a copy and rename
            :: copy "!src!" "!dest!\%newname%"  1>nul
  )
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the outside loop doesn't increment"?  Do you mean `Count` doesn't increment?  Because count is in your *inside* loop, and it appears to be the only thing you're trying to increment, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry. 1st post. My src var (%%G) always equals 1st line in filelist.txt while dest var goes through lines of folderlist as desired. (I'll take out the counter.)

Comment: your code runs fine here (although I don't know, if it runs how you expect it to run) - with one excepion: label `:end` does not exist, so it doesn't exit when the counter reaches endcount. Replacing it with `goto :eof` helps.

Comment: Does your file organization structure should looks like this one:
Folder1 - File1, File2, File3, File4, File5...
Folder2 - File1, File2, File3, File4, File5...
Folder3 - File1, File2, File3, File4, File5...
....

Comment: Rafael: No. The files to be copied are in desktop/sub. The number of files varies but is always fewer than folders. I will copy some files multiple times to fill up the folders. This is why I want/need to work from a filelist. Files go into "sub3" folders in structure like desktop/sub/sub1/sub2/sub3 where there are multiple sub2 folders, each with one sub3 under it. (hope helps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code is not the syntax, but the concept. Your code reads a line from list of files and then, for this line, reads all the lines in the folder list.

If you have nested `for` loops, for each iteration of the outer `for` all iterations of the inner loop are executed.

If you need a synchronized line read from the two files, you need something like

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    < files (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in (folders) do (
            set /p "myFile="
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for /f "delims=" %%b in ("!myFile!") do (
                endlocal
                echo %%a %%b
            )
        )
    )
```

That is, the folder list is read with the `for` command, and the file list, is read from the standard input with a `set /p`. Since we are redirecting the file list as input, the `set /p` will get its data from it.

Comment: thats genius! but i guess you can just remove the inner for, and use the myfile directly.

Comment: @speising, as i don't know how the files/folders references will be handled, and to avoid problems with possible exclamations in the values, it is better to handle the values with delayed expansion disabled. But we need it enabled to read the variable. So, the `for` is included to read the variable value (with delayed expansion active), store it in the `for` replaceable parameter and then disable delayed expansion to prevent problems. Can the `for` be removed? Probably yes, but without more information/code i'm not sure.

Comment: EDIT: File info (%%b) isn't echoing. MC! This is most likely it. Makes sense as you explain it. Need to test little more. Weird thing: echo output to file only gives 4 of 37 folder paths. Run in editor (very strange) I'm getting paths tracking back to original location on android device, which doesn't appear in folderlist!! More investigation.

Comment: @user338032, i've readed your last comment in the question. If the file list is shorter than the folder list you can not do a synchronized file-folder read. Can you include in the question a sample of your files and the criteria to reuse files to fill the folders?

Comment: @MCND, lists are same length. I build filelist with duplicate files to=folders. Re:^weird output & no echo=my bad input. Think your way will work. Will post more info or vote this answer after tests. THX!