# batch read from different text files and execute cURL

Tags: windows, web-services, rest, batch-file, curl

I am trying to automate testing a list of RESTful web services by combining Windows BATCH scripts and cURL tool. Being a newbie to BATCH scripting, I am unable to proceed after a certain point.

I have two text files. 
one(URLs.properties) to store all the REST webservice URLs and other to store the corresponding input parameters(params.properties).

In essence, I want to read the `URLs.properties`, fetch the first WebService URL, read the `params.properties`to fetch the corresponding input parameters and call cURL for this set of data.

Currently I have the following approach:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%I IN (URLs.properties) do (
call :fetchParams
)
:fetchParams
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%K IN (params.properties) do (
REM read the input params and call CURL for first URL
goto :callCURL
)
:callCURL

curl -L -v  -X POST -c cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json %%J -d %%L -o "%%I.json"

pause
```

This is flawed because it executes all the input parameters for one URL before moving to the next.
But I am looking for a way that executes the cURL statement for one URL from the `URLs.properties` and the corresponding input from `params.properties`.

How can I achieve this using a Windows BATCH file?

P.S: I have read a few related questions and solutions and have tried to modify them according to my needs. But I am not able to arrive at a working solution

Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25520053/2861476) could help.

Comment: @MCND - That was awesome! I can't thank you enough! :) 
One question though - Some of the web services don't accept any input params. In that case, I have fewer input params than services. As you have already explained in one of your comments , if the entries are not same in both files, synchronized read is not possible. So, to overcome this, I have created corresponding entries in `params.txt` with blank values(empty input strings). Hopefully, this approach is correct. Would love to hear your thoughts on this, please. Thanks again!